# CSS Flexbox - Popup is still Beholden to Parent Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have some basic code that allows for a popup to appear when something is hovered over. Codepen: https://codepen.io/Sean713/pen/GRBpVOZ

```css
.row {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.subdiv {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hover:hover+.popup {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="subdiv">
    <p class="hover">Hover</p>
    <div class="popup">
      <p>Surprise I am a popup</p>
      <p> and so am I</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since `.row` is a flexbox, it makes sense that `.subdiv` should compress its width to its content, as I have not specified otherwise.

However, the popup that appears when I hover is having unexpected behavior. The actual text inside the `p` tags is wrapping and is only as wide as the longest word in the sentence, it seems to be acting almost like `.subdiv`. I'm not sure why this is the case or why the fact that `.row` being a flexbox is influencing this popup. I would like for the `p` tags inside the popup to full block and allow the popup to wrap around that.

Edit: Adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the `p` tag fixes it, but I don't understand why the wrapping issue occurs in the first place.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? `popup` is inside `subdiv`, so if you don't give the absolutely positioned `popup` a width, it'll try and match the nearest positioned ancestor's width (which is `subdiv`).

Comment: I did not realize that if no width was defined it would try and match a width- I thought it would simply act as a new div and the p elements would block it. What is the suggested fix?

Comment: In the codepen you provided the `.subdiv` is `positon: relative;` and the popup, its child, is `absolute`. 

`abolute` elements are removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. **It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor**. (The `.subdiv`). Though its removed from document flow, it is still positioned off of the `.subdiv` and inheriting it's width.

If you remove the `relative` positioning from the `.subdiv`, it will behave as you expect. Either that or you can manually set the width on the popup.

Comment: By "block it" I'm guessing you mean make the width `100%` since it's a block element. It does do that, but `100%` of what? Answer (in this case) would be the parent.

Comment: Justin, that mostly makes sense. I understand the positioning is relative but I didn't realize the width is inherited. The problem is I need the popup to position relative to where `.subdiv` is but I don't want the width to be compressed. I also don't want to manually set a width, I want it to compress to the content, since I am not sure of the font size the user is using.

Comment: Salif, I did not think about the 100% width, what you say makes sense. What would the best solution be if I want to keep the positioning relative to `.subdiv` but have a width that fits to the content?

Comment: There a number of different ways you could solve this, but I think I would need more context on the use case. 

You could set a manual vw width or create a placeholder `div` and position it off of that just to name some quick ones.

Comment: You could use `white-space: nowrap` or `width: max-content` if you don't want the container to break a `p` into multiple lines, but that's not a good solution either since a really long paragraph will go off the screen. You'll need to create some more restraints to solve the problem.